# Authenticate to query a Fusion Table using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I am a member of a Google Apps domain and I am trying to use the code examples to query a fusion table but keep getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "required",
      "message": "Login Required",
      "locationType": "header",
      "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Login Required"
  }
}
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
function myFunction() {

//Fusion Table
  var constructor = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=';
  var fusionTableID = '1pJk********UY5l';
  var fusionTableAPIKey = 'AIza********AGV8';  //  Browser API Key
  var fusionTableQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + fusionTableID + '&key=' + fusionTableAPIKey;  
  var queryString = constructor + fusionTableQuery;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryString);

  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  Logger.log(parsedResponse);

}
```

Unfortunately, due to domain settings, I am unable to share any of the files with people outside of our domain.  I have reviewed the reference [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/apps_script?hl=en) but I am unsure how to adapt it to what I am doing.

I can get the script to work using this sample string from Google so I am confident that the code is right:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v2/query?sql=SELECT * FROM%201KxVV0wQXhxhMScSDuqr-0Ebf0YEt4m4xzVplKd4&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the authorization header in the request, with either the access token or login auth. It is shown in the [link](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/apps_script?hl=en) you posted.

Anyway, it is much easier to just use the Fusion Table advanced service. To enable it go to Resources > Advanced Google Services > Fusion Tables API.

If you still want to do the call manually. At least enable the service and put some fake code so Apps Script can request the oAuth2 scope for you. e.g.

```js
function noNeedToRun() //just to trigger the scope
  FusionTables.Query.sql('foo'); //although this is easier than UrlFetch`ing manually
}

function myFunction() {
  //...your same code
  var queryString = constructor + fusionTableQuery;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryString, {
    headers: { //this is what you're missing
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  });

  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  Logger.log(parsedResponse);
}
```

Comment: thank you, that worked beautifully!  I know that Apps Script is supposed to handle the oAuth but could not get the screen to come up.  Makes sense now...  Looking forward to exploring FusionTables.Query.sql.  Right now this is just a bridge, my real problem is querying a Google Sheet server side from Google Script...